# How to test a simple method that returns void in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, cypress

I have the following function that I'd like to test with Cypress:

```
let stopped = false; // global variable

export const = stopDoingStuff = () => {
 stopped = true;
}
```

I want to test if the methods sets the variable `stopped` to `true`, after calling it.

This is my current state. I don't know how the check the global variable after calling the function...

```
it('should set stopped to true', async () => {
  let stopped = false;
  stopDoingStuff();
  expect(stopped).to.equal(true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's always better to also mention what the result of your code is.

But I can see that variable `stopDoingStuff` is exported, so I assume the whole piece of code is in a separate module. Since `stopped` variable is not exported, you can't access it from anywhere but the module it's in.